# How to get IE9 standards support for dialogs opened by HTA?

Tags: internet-explorer, modal-dialog, hta

I'm translating some of my old HTAs from Quirks to IE9 standards. However, it seems that modal and modeless dialogs opened by HTA don't support IE9 standards mode.

Test dialog:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>TestDialog</title>
<meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=9" />
</head>
<body>
<svg>
    <circle cx="100" cy="100" r="50" fill="#0f0" />
</svg>
</body>
</html>
```

In the HTA main page:

```
<button onclick="showModalDialog(...)">Modal</button>
<button onclick="showModelessDialog(...)">Modeless</button>
```

When opening TestDialog from HTA, it's empty. If the main page is a regular html-document, the green circle appears in the dialog. When opening from HTA, there's no difference if the dialog file itself were htm or hta.

I've also tested `addEventListener()` but it also won't work in dialogs.

So, can I "force" dialogs to support IE9 standards when opening from HTA?

---

**EDIT**

It seems that modal and modeless dialogs opened from HTA are on the level of IE8. This same happens when using IE10 in Windows7.

Answer (score 2):

A quick Google of the keywords in this question gave me this page on Microsoft MSDN site: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/subscriptions/ms536496(v=vs.85).aspx

The answer to your question is on tha page. The answer is to add an `x-ua-compatible` meta tag to your HTML's `<head>` section.

To quote:

> By default, HTAs display webpages in Compatibility View, which displays standards-mode content in IE7 Standards mode and quirks mode content in IE5 (Quirks) mode. To utilize features available to current versions of Internet Explorer, use the meta element to define an X-UA-Compatible header for your HTA

The tag would look like this:

```
<meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=9">
```

The above is according to the MSDN site. In fact, I'd suggest that using `content="ie=edge"` would be better than specifying IE9 mode. Otherwise you'll lose out on any new features in IE10 when you upgrade to that.

Comment: Thanks for an answer, but as you can see in my example, there is `x-ua-compatible` included in the code already (in main page too). All "HTML5-stuff" is working in main page, but not in dialogs ={. I've also tried `IE=edge`, unfortenately it didn't help either.

Comment: Hmm. That's a pain. I was hoping `edge` would do it. Does the example from the MSDN site work for you?

Comment: Not in dialog boxes, only in main HTA. If the main page is HTM, also dialog boxes support IE9 standards. Maybe MS has forgotten to update mshta.exe for dialog boxes?

Comment: heh. I wouldn't put it past them.  :-/ Ouch. Clutching at straws now... have you tried any other doctypes? XHTML standards, maybe? I know you'd lose the SVG support, but maybe you could at least trigger IE8 standards mode... it'd beat Quirks mode, anyway.

Comment: I just tested your idea. It seems I've tumbled with JSON, it's working (also with HTML5 doctype), but `addEventListener()` and `svg`s are not. `svg` and `canvas` are the main elements, why I started this translation in first place. They were supposed to replace old WZ_jsgraphics-library.

Comment: it appears that using the x-ua meta 9+ tag breaks the features of the HTA:APPLICATION tag options

Comment: @Fowl - yes, it does, because HTA was a non-standard feature that Microsoft added in earlier IE versions. From IE9 onward, they made a point of only supporting the W3C standards, and deprecated and removed their non-standard features. HTA has been obsolete for a very long time. If you're still using it for anything significant then you will need to rewrite that code.