# Open HTML5 window from non-HTML5 window in IE (Internet Explorer)

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer

We have a thin client business app, and we are heading to use HTML5 on client side (first only for specific tasks, like some SVG drag'n'drop UI and Canvas image generating).

I know, I can't call a HTML5 page in an iframe on a non-HTML5 page in Internet Explorer, because it will displayed as non-HTML5 page, like its parent.

I tought i can call it to a new window, via javascript.
But it isn't work too.
In the base app there is an
open.window('HTML5.asp','_blank')
function, where the HTML5.asp uses SVG and Canvas. And yes, it's tested, it's works, when called from a HTML5 environment.

There are any solution or workaround to make it work?
Thank you guys!

**UPDATE**

Thank you for your help, finally i found the mistake.
I've tried to create a simplified code for you, but i couldn't reproduce the bug, so i went over our algorithm again, first block by block, then line by line.

We have a function dictonary, what should be the same in all systems, but it doesn't :)
And i've used a formatting function from there, and the HTML5 page has crased, due to it.

Thank you, again :)

Comment: I can't understand why it won't work in a new window. do you have some code to show or some jsfiddle for example?

Comment: Unfortenately I don't know answer to this question, but I'm going to follow this post very careful, since I'm having quite similar problems with IE ( http://stackoverflow.com/q/11727815/1169519 ).

Comment: I suggest a: don't use that window open function, use a link or your own custom function without window size limits. And b: post sample code.

Comment: I'm simplifing the code, then i'll copy it in the question.

Answer (score 0):

That's quite a coincidence: I was just, by chance, reading about the [Google Chrome Frame](http://www.google.com/chromeframe) IE plugin that apparently allows you to use Webkit and the V8 JS engine in IE.

In the web page, we add the tag:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="chrome=1" />
```

(Of course, Chrome Frame needs to be installed. If it's not, perhaps a redirection to an installer might be an option...)

As I said, I just happened to be reading about this a few minutes before I saw your question, so I don't know if this would be of any use to you (nor do I have experience using it).

Good luck!