# external CSS not honored in HTA popup

Tags: html, css, popup, hta

This problem is killing me. Searched the web for 2 days now and beginning to feel like I'm the only one who's experiencing this issue (???). Here's the problem:

A simple HTA that uses CSS3 rule to format background. The rule is in an external .css file that is being included in both the main and a child HTA files:

## `common.css`

```
body{
  background-image:
    -ms-radial-gradient(top, circle cover, #3c3b52 0%, #252233 80%);
  color: rgba(255,255,255,0.6);
}
```

## `main.hta`

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <HTA:application id="main" applicationName="CSS3 HTA" />

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="common.css" />
</head>
<body>
    <p>Click the button to pop a new window up</p>
    <button onclick="window.showModelessDialog('child.hta');">
        popup window
    </button>
</body>
</html>
```

## `child.hta`

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <HTA:application id="child" applicationName="CSS3 HTA (popup)" />

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="common.css" />
</head>
<body>
    Hello, world! Where's my CSS3 background?!?
</body>
</html>
```

Running the `child.hta` on its own as a standalone app shows the (proper) CSS3 background as specified in the rules. But when opening it as a child modeless dialog box (or modal) the CSS rules are not honored (any CSS rules, versions 1.0, 2.0, 2.1, 3.0).

I'm using

```
<meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="IE=edge" />
```

and having no luck at all (also tried with `"IE=9"` option - same negative result).

Does anyone know how to make this work? How to make the `common.css` properly apply to an HTA's pop-up window?

Than you for your time

## ***UPDATE***

Though this is not strictly speaking an answer to the question but this works for what I need (an independent window running some extra functionality):

```
<button onclick="(new ActiveXObject('WScript.Shell')).Run('child.hta', 1)">
    new HTA window
</button>
```

Essentially instead of popping up a dialog window the code is launching an instance of HTA. And then the full "new IE" support is back.
Although that seems to bring a new issue - that launched HTA doesn't honor the `singleInstance="yes"` directive! /shake-fist-at-MS

Comment: Looks like modal and modeless dialogs are run in IE8 mode, nevertheless how "new" DTD and/or `x-ua` are set. I.e. no support for  `-ms-radial-gradient` in dialogs. I've asked [about this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11727815/1169519) over year ago, but no luck yet... In the meanwhile, I've created my own modal dialogs though.

Comment: What do you mean by "created my own modal dialogs"? Could you elaborate on that, please?

Comment: Since I couldn't apply modern standards in dialogs, I created my own modal dialog system using a template HTA file and a couple of ActiveXs, i.e. `Scripting.FileSystemObject`, `WScript.Shell` and  `WbemScripting.SWbemLocator`.

Comment: This is not really an answer to your question, but when I was faced with a similar problem (I needed a popup that extended [way] past `InputBox`'s functionality) I actually ended up creating a hidden `div` with absolute coordinates that functioned as a "popup". Instead of calling the other .hta, I just did `divname.style.display = ""` then hid it again when `Submit` was pressed. (I say this because I looked into your issue, and was able to recreate the problem and I couldn't find a solution.)

Comment: @YePhIcK That's how I started to implement my own dialog system too. After that stage I did this: `isDialog = shell.Run(sys.defRoot + appPath, 1, true);` to stop the script, then `window.focusin = shell.AppActivate(apptitle)` to make a real modal. I write/read dialog arguments to/from a temporary file. And finally used [WMI](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14042537/1169519), if user closed the main app from the Task Bar.

Comment: @Teemu - thank you, that explanation was much more useful to me than the previous one.