# Third Party HTML5 .HTA Application?

Tags: jquery, css, html, hta

Is there any chance there is a program just like .hta applications only it supports HTML5, CSS3, jQuery, etc? I'd love to be able to run my local files without chrome...

Anybody know if this exists? Maybe even some way to make .hta application fully support those programming languages?

Comment: What is your target platform?

Comment: windows 10 home edition

Comment: just found <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge" />, but that is ie, if there is a way for the functionality of chrome that'd be even better

Comment: HTAs use IE's Trident rendering engine. There's no way to switch it out for another one. Which "functionality of chrome" were you hoping for, anyway? If your HTA can use the latest IE engine, there's not a huge amount to choose between them. HTML5, CSS3, jQuery as you mentioned should all work.

Comment: Chromium Embedded Framework is one C++ framework which will let you create embedded app using web interface.

Comment: Perhaps you're looking form something like [Electron](https://github.com/electron/electron).

Answer (score -2, accepted):

```
<meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie-edge">
```

This gives functionality of edge into a .HTA file.

Very handy!

Comment: Doubtful. This has nothing to do with Edge. See http://stackoverflow.com/q/6771258/306930 and http://stackoverflow.com/q/11727815/306930 and https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/subscriptions/ms536496(v=vs.85).aspx